# Inconsistent results when memory profiling Cordova app on iOS vs native app

Tags: ios, cordova, out-of-memory, instruments, infinite-scroll

I'm getting out of memory crashes with a Cordova app on an iPhone 4S running iOS 7. I am try to implement an infinite scrolling list and I start seeing memory pressure and hiccups when prepending to the list (appending seems fine). When I run the Allocations widget in Instruments, I see a crash when there are 20 MB of allocated Live Bytes.

[image]

Here's the interesting part: This Cordova app is replacing a native one that has been available on the App Store for a number of years without issue. When I profile the native app, I see the memory go above 20 MB, but the app doesn't suffer from any memory-related crashes.

[image]

Why does the native app continue to run fine after surpassing 20 MB of Live Bytes while the Cordova app terminates? Does the Allocations widget not properly take into account the memory usage of the UIWebView Cordova uses? Or is there some other resource not being taken into account?

**After more investigation**

I ran the tests again using the Memory Monitor. Here are the results of the Cordova app:

[image]

And the native app:

[image]

I think this brings us closer to the answer. Both apps have similar Real Memory usage, but the Virtual Memory is dramatically higher in the Cordova app. I'm not sure what causes this and why this isn't reflected in the Allocations widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the Allocation widget is inaccurate for total memory usage and it was best to just use the Real Memory + Virtual Memory numbers from the Memory Monitor widget. This is pretty much the only option when developing Cordova apps since the UIWebView is a black box and difficult to profile.